# Create Interactive message from bot

Tags: slack-api

I want to ask an interactive question in slack using slackbot. I want to achieve the same functionality using slackbot which we can achieve using slash commands.

My slackbot is receiving an event which contains the username of the slack. I want my slackbot to ask a question to the user whether he wants tea or coffee.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please review what constitutes a good question to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am also not looking for code. I was just looking for hints since i was not getting one while searching. Anyways don't bother I will find solution to my problem you keep on finding the purpose of this platform

Comment: Sorry SO can not help you with your issue, but your question is way too broad. SO is designed to solve specific and concrete issues, not have a broad discussion. In your case I would suggest to ask here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/

Comment: But feel free to ask another question if you have a specific programming issue, e.g. with existing code to show.